# OOP: relying on protected properties in a class-subclass contract

Tags: python, oop

I'm coding in Python, but the question seems independent of programming language.

I have a class that represents some system check:

```
class Check:
   @abstractmethod
   def run()
     """ You have to define your own run(). As a result, it must set self._ok. """
      ...

   @property
   def is_ok():
      return self._is_ok
```

Then we have a set of checks by subclassing Check class, and they're used in the following way (simplified):

```
class Checker:
    checks = [check1, check2...]

    def __call__(self):
        for check in self.checks:
            if not check.is_ok:
                alarm()
```

The question is: Is it fine to oblige subclass to set some protected object attributes?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for (and may already be answered on) programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess it may be acceptable.

You could also consider to let the subclasses implement their own is_ok() method rather then modify a protected attribute, so they can implement their own check strategy.

Comment: My concern is: Isn't it too much to explain to the child class, and isn't it too hard to verify if child class fits this contract?

Comment: I don't believe it will be too hard to verify: if you initialize the value in the base class the check would fail unless the property is modified accordingly, you may also leave it undefined and check if it was set to false or true in run(). I would say if you need to bring this to someone else then it may be better to let them implement the is_ok() method, otherwise it will be acceptable as you don't need to worry on how to document it properly and how to check.